# Apply ifelse test to previous values?

Tags: r

What I need to do is test the prior n number of rows (say 5 for a nice round number) of a `data.frame`. This is really easy for just one, where it's

```
for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
ifelse(((data$V1[i]>(mean(data$V1)+2*sd(data$V1))) & 
(data$V1[i-1]>(mean(data$V1)+2*sd(data$V1)))),Control[i,1]<-1,Control[i,1]<-0)
}
```

This works and Control is filled with 1s if the test is true and 0 if it is false.

However, I want to extend it to several more in the past, which I attempt to do with a nested for like so:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(data$V1)){ifelse((data$V1[i]>(mean(data$V1)+sd(data$V1))) &
(for (j in 1:4){(data$V1[(i-j)]>(mean(data$V1)+sd(data$V1)))},
Control[i,1]<-1,Control[i,1]<-0)}
```

This gives the following error (for simplicity I test with a single vector of values, called `test` ):

```
Error: unexpected ',' in "for (i in 1:length(test)){ifelse((test[i]>(mean(test)+sd(test))) & (for (j in 1:4){(test[(i-j)]>(mean(test)+sd(test)))},"
```

Trying to pad it with some parens gives the following slightly different error:

```
Error: unexpected ')' in "for (i in 1:length(test)){ifelse((test[i]>(mean(test)+sd(test))) & (for (j in 1:4){(test[(i-j)]>(mean(test)+sd(test))))"
```

`test` is defined like so:

```
test <- c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 7, 7)
```

Any help with my method, or a more efficient R method (I'm still new to the language!) is extremely welcome.

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to test for in your previous values?

Comment: So you're trying to test whether the current value, as well as the `n` values immediately before it, are outliers?

Comment: And outliers in the sense that they're greater than `mean + 2 standard deviations`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need `rollapply` from `zoo` package. But it is not clear how you define your loop since you use `data`? `Control` and yo give an error in a test object.... Here I check if the current value and 4 previous values are all less than a certain value (outlier). No need to use `ifelse` here since the condition is not a vector.

```
test <- c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
          4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
          4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 7, 7)
library(zoo)
V <- mean(test)+2*sd(test)
rollapply(test,5,function(x)if(all(x>V)) 1 else 0)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is precisely what I wanted - it does the test and lets me skip the for looping. (These sets may get large in the future.)

Comment: Shouldn't this have `fill=NA` specified too? Otherwise it will be too short.